# remove lvs with specific attribute

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6, lvm

I found that there are many zombie LV in my CentOS 6 server which is being used for KVM vps hosting with LVM storage. Their attribute is "-wi-a-----" while normal LV attribute is "-wi-ao----". What I am doing now is exporting the lv list using "lvs" command and then filtering those LV with "-wi-a-----" attribute. 
Now I am looking for a command to remove these zombies in a faster way, like using lvremove -f xxxxxx.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't do that!**

The missing `o` flag simply means that a Logical Volume is not opened, so no processes are using it. However, this does *not* means that you can safely remote it: maybe it's corresponding VPS is simply powered-off, but it can be powered-on at any time.

If you remove all not opened LV, without a deep understanding of what is stored on them, you really risk to lose data.

Comment: Yes, I found it. So I will make sure they are not powered off before deleting.